# What are the URLs for IntelliJ updates and plugins repository for adding a firewall exception?

Tags: intellij-idea

My organization has a firewall, so I am unable to browse IntelliJ-idea plugins repository. Also I get this error when I try to check for updates - "Connection failed (connect timed out). Please check network connection and try again." This is because of the firewall blocking these URLs.

My network admin needs absolute URLs to add firewall exceptions.

Can someone please provide the same?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- https://www.jetbrains.com/updates/updates.xml
- https://download.jetbrains.com
- https://download-cf.jetbrains.com
- https://plugins.jetbrains.com
- https://account.jetbrains.com

Note that you may have problems downloading plugins since the direct download links will look like `https://d9ernfkkvx1zk.cloudfront.net/4230/34743/BashSupport-1.6.9.171.zip` until the redirects are configured properly (it's work in progress).

Comment: I asked our systems team to follow your advice and they were able to get through the firewall.